# BOOTMGR not found

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootmgr

I had to force shut down my computer twice today because it froze for an unknown reason. The first time I tried starting the PC again worked out but now I get the following error message every time I try to boot from my hard disk where Windows was installed.

> BOOTMGR is missing
>   Press Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart.

I've also tried using my Windows 7 installation CD to get into the recovery options but it says that the version of Windows I have installed (Windows 7 Home Premium) is not compatible with the version of that CD (also Windows 7 Home Premium). Does anyone have a clue how I could fix this?

EDIT: Seems like the cable to the system hard drive was loose. Now I "only" get a bluescreen when I boot up Windows. It disappears far too fast to copy any information from there, though.

EDIT 2: This is strange. I switched the SATA mode from IDE back to AHCI and now not only the bluescreen is gone but everything works fine so far (at least until the login screen)

**Specs**

- Processor: Intel i5-2500K @ 3.30GHz
- Mainboard: AsRock Z77 Extreme 4
- RAM: 2x 4GB (DDR3-1600), 1x 8GB (DDR3-1600)
- Graphics: GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 660 Ti

Comment: Maybe make sure the CD's service pack matches the installed one.

Comment: First, make sure it is not trying to bootup to secondary hard drive or removable usb thumb drive. Disconnect all secondary hard drives. Chances are with prior freezes, this is not the problem. Second, shutdown computer and check loose hard drive cables. Third, the problem probably has to do with corrupt and or misconfigured files, hard drive and operating system upgrade issues, corrupt hard drive sectors...

Comment: @Logman Wow. I don't know what happened, but I just went into the BIOS configuration screen and back and it's _somewhat_ back to normal. I'm in the startup recovery screen right now, it didn't complain about a missing BOOTMGR anymore.

Comment: I've had this exact symptom with a failing hard drive. Have you checked the smart data for the drive?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure it is not trying to bootup to secondary hard drive
   or removable usb thumb drive. Disconnect all secondary hard drives.
   Chances are with prior freezes, this is not the problem.
2. Shutdown computer and check loose hard drive cables.
3. Boot up to startup recovery and open a cmd prompt and run the following:

> chkdsk /f C:
>
> sfc.exe /scannow

The problem is probably due to corrupt and or misconfigured files, hard drive and operating system upgrade issues, or corrupt hard drive sectors...

Comment: Well, actually, it started working again "just like that". I don't know why or how but that's how it is. Still, thanks for your answer!